# Combine data from multiple DataFrames into single plot w/o combining DataFrames

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Due to memory constraints, I cannot have all data loaded into my jupyter notebook at once to generate a desired plot. The solution I came up with is to incrementally load my data and update the plot with data from each DataFrame. Here is a dummy example of what I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbn

df1 = pd.DataFrame({100 : [1,2,3], 200: [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({300 : [4,5,6], 400: [5,6,7]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({500 : [11,12,13,14], 600: [12,13,14,15]})

ax = plt.subplot(111)

sbn.boxplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', color = 'yellow',
            data = pd.melt(df1), ax = ax)

sbn.boxplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', color = 'yellow',
            data = pd.melt(df2), ax = ax)

sbn.boxplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', color = 'yellow', 
            data = pd.melt(df3), ax = ax)
```

which results in this plot:
[image]

I would like the end product to look like this:

[image]

Any insight would be very welcomed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `order = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]` and pass it in each call to `boxplot`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the dataframes before calling `melt`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({100 : [1,2,3], 200: [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({300 : [4,5,6], 400: [5,6,7]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({500 : [11,12,13,14], 600: [12,13,14,15]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', color = 'yellow',
            data = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).melt(), ax = ax)
```

[image: concatenating, then melt]